# Incorrect behavior of groupby with "datetime64[ns, UTC]" sampling in pandas 1.0.1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to groupby a dataframe by column `f493` such that I sample values in column "f496" and this is what I get

```
>>> df
       f493                       f496
0  344448.0  2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
1  372673.5  2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
2  372673.5  2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
>>> df["f493"]
0    344448.0
1    372673.5
2    372673.5
Name: f493, dtype: float64
>>> df["f496"]
0    2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
1    2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
2    2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
Name: f496, dtype: object
>>> df = df.groupby("f493").aggregate({"f496": lambda x: x.sample(1)})
>>> df["f496"]
f493
344448.0    2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
372673.5    2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
Name: f496, dtype: object
```

Why column `f493` now contains value of column `f493`?

I expected result

```
       f493                       f496
0  344448.0  2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
1  372673.5  2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
```

e.g simply sample value in column `f496`.

EDIT: **The actual issue starts here...**

Even more wrong behavior if we turn column "f496" to a datetime type

```
 df = df.astype({"f493":"float64", "f496":"datetime64[ns, UTC]"})
```

The output is a complete mess.

```
>>> df["f496"]
f493
344448.0                            2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
372673.5    1   2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
Name: f496, dtyp...
Name: f496, dtype: object
```

I do not know what is going on..

```
>>> pd.__version__
'1.0.1'
```

Comma-separated df source

```
f493,f496
344448.0,2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
372673.5,2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
372673.5,2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
```

EDIT:

```
>>> df['f496'] = pd.to_datetime(df['f496'])
>>> df = df.groupby("f493").aggregate({"f496": lambda x: x.sample(1)}).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
                                                f496
0                          2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
1  2   2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
Name: f496, dtyp...
>>> df["f496"]
0                            2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
1    2   2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
Name: f496, dtyp...
Name: f496, dtype: object
```

Comment: I think you need `df = df.groupby("f493").aggregate({"f496": lambda x: x.sample(1)}).reset_index()`, right?

Comment: because output of `df = df.groupby("f493").aggregate({"f496": lambda x: x.sample(1)})` is `Series`

Comment: @jezrael ok, can you tho try with setting datetime format? resetting index does not seem to help in this case. maybe i should make separate question for it

Comment: For datetimes use `df['f496'] = pd.to_datetime(df['f496'])`

Comment: I do, then I just save dtypes in json and reuse them later on... and this is the mess I get.. do you know why this happens? datetime type seems to be set no problem but then aggregation is a mess, why so?

Comment: I think `"f496":"datetime64[ns, UTC]"` is wrong way for convert to datetimes, need  `df['f496'] = pd.to_datetime(df['f496'])`

Comment: @jezrael this is exactly the type it resolves to... and same repeats

Comment: hmmm, so do you use `df = df.groupby("f493").aggregate({"f496": lambda x: x.sample(1)}).reset_index()` and then it fail?

Comment: because for me it working perfectly (if added `.reset_index()`)

Comment: @jezrael yes, I added extra info to the post. Can you check? Does it look right?
Do you have same version with me?

Comment: hmmm, not tested in `1.0.1` version, but I think here is necessary alternative `df = df.groupby("f493", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1))`

Comment: @jezrael in my actual use case I have many columns of different types so I specify in the dictionary what kind of aggregation I want , sampling, mean, etc. I don't think this would work. I am not really sure what;s going on, looks like a bug to me, coz it seems ok with object type.

Comment: OK, understand, can you test `df = df.groupby("f493").agg({"f496": lambda x: x.sample(1).iat[0]}).reset_index()` ?

Comment: @jezrael oh wow , this seems to do a trick. Damn, why .iat[0] is required here. Well at least it works on this toy task, I will check on my actual use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is there is returned one item `Series`, not scalar.

Solution is convert `Series` to scalar by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df['f496'] = pd.to_datetime(df['f496'])
df = df.groupby("f493").agg({"f496": lambda x: x.sample(1).iat[0]}).reset_index()
print (df)
       f493                      f496
0  344448.0 2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
1  372673.5 2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
```

Btw, it seems bug in `pandas 1.0.1`, because in pandas 0.23.1 both solutions working perfectly:

```
df['f496'] = pd.to_datetime(df['f496'])
df = df.groupby("f493").agg({"f496": lambda x: x.sample(1)}).reset_index()
print (df)
       f493                      f496
0  344448.0 2016-11-21 14:26:56+00:00
1  372673.5 2016-08-17 18:15:54+00:00
```